How to disable log for images and CSS files in springboot
I my SpringBoot application I added logs but when I run the application I am getting unwanted logs like css, imgs etc that I didn't to see in Logs.
I only want to see logs that has only I mentioned in my application.
I want to disable style.css logs and imgs logs

please show the unwanted logs

YOu added logs how? Show configuration, code etc.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

if you want to disable spring framework and only see your own logs use can use the following property:
logging.level.org.springframework=OFF

I would however not recommend it since if an exception happens then you won't see it. Setting it to WARN will only show WARN and ERROR messages:
logging.level.org.springframework=WARN


the usual approach is to identify few annoying logs and only turn those off:
logging.level.org.springframework.foo=OFF
logging.level.org.springframework.bar=OFF

